# Dynamically convert an RDB to RDF

Tags: rdf, virtuoso, linked-data

I am using Virtuoso Open Source Edition.

My question is how can I dynamically convert an RDB to RDF?

Let's say we have a Relational Database which we need to convert to RDF, but at the same time this Database needs to be updated all the time.

Is there a way to continuously update the RDF Graph based on the new entries of the Relational Database?

So far I have found [this tutorial](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRdb2RDFViewsGeneration#Manual%20Linked%20Data%20Generation%20&%20Deployment%20using%20the%20Conductor%27s%20HTML-based%20wizard) 
thanks to which I can convert an RDB to RDF but I have to redo the process if I need to update the database.
In the beginning of the tutorial it says:

> > Virtuoso includes an HTML-based Wizard interface for dynamically generating & publishing RDF-based Linked Data

Please correct me if I am wrong here but I don't see how this can be dynamical. All I do is generate linked data based on the current tables.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to *present a view* of an relational database as RDF data.  Is that right?

Comment: I have already done this. What i am asking if it can somehow be autoupdated along with the rdb

Comment: That sort of what I meant by "view".  You don't necessarily care about actually having RDF data on hand;  you just want to be able to query the database *as though* it were RDF.

Comment: Yes that's what I want but in the tutorial that I provided it doesn't seem like it

Comment: Actually, in reading the tutorial, it sounds like this *is a dynamic view* (but I could certainly be wrong).  After you've done this, if you make changes in the database, you don't see the corresponding changes in the results of SPARQL queries?

Comment: I'll try it and inform you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamism of Linked Data Views is in the data you see through the VIEW.  The definition of the VIEW is not itself dynamic.  Schema definitions of RDB databases are typically fairly static; changes here are not reflected automatically through Virtuoso's Linked Data Views.  Data in RDF databases is typically fairly dynamic; changes here are reflected automatically and immediately (usually -- you may choose to make this happen periodically instead) through Virtuoso's Linked Data Views.

Also note -- [VOS (the Open Source Edition of Virtuoso)](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSIndex) can only present Linked Data Views of RDB data *within* Virtuoso.  If you want to present a Linked Data View of RDB data in a remote data source (Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, Informix, Ingres, DB2, Progress/OpenEdge, PostgreSQL, MySQL, or pretty much any other ODBC accessible DBMS), you'll need the [Commercial Edition of Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/download/). Other [differences between the Editions may be seen here](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/features-comparison-matrix/).